# Mixed Hodge structure and cup product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, hodge-theory, hodge-structure

I'm looking for a reference for the answer to the following questions.

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over C. When is the cup product a morphism of Mixed Hodge structures? Does $X$ have to be smooth?

Comment: Is the variety over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: This is true with no hypothesis on $X$: see Corollaire 8.2.11 in Deligne *Théorie de Hodge* III, Pub. Math. IHES 44 (1974), p. 5-77.

Comment: @abx  You should write that as an answer!

Comment: Also, seriously?  3 close votes?  I understand it's not the best written question and the answer is reasonably "well-known," but mixed Hodge structures are too basic for this site now?

Comment: I had similar thoughts. I wonder how many people who voted to close knew the answer. (Test: Is the category of mixed Hodge structures Tannakian, true of false?)

Comment: @Ben Webster: done (and I am also surprised by the downvotes).

Answer (score 9):

This is true with no hypothesis on X: see Corollaire 8.2.11 in Deligne Théorie de Hodge III, Pub. Math. IHES 44 (1974), p. 5-77.